# Which formula should I use for 30/60/90 days overdue with a pivot table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that shows 30 days over due and 90 days overdue.
Columns and relative formulas:

```
 G                 H                                    I                            O
```

Aging           |CountAging                          |ActualAging                |StatusDate
TODAY()-O102    IF(G102>90,90,IF(G102>30,30,0))    NETWORKDAYS(O102,TODAY())       [list of dates]

```
  N                 P
```

[list of names]    [Title Code]

The pivot table
[image: Spreadsheet and Pivot]

I tried changing column H to MAX(30,MIN(G2,90)). That worked on the sheet, but the pivot table returned waaaay to many results. (count of count aging).

I also tried using three columns, by inserting two columns after H and and adding Max formulas there:

```
H  MAX(30,MIN(G2,30))
I  MAX(30,MIN(G2,60))
J  MAX(30,MIN(G2,60))
```

That worked in the pivot, but not on the main sheet.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!